# How to modifiy a specific caracter from DataFrame date in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

here is a script :

```
date = ['1871-01', '1871-02', '1871-1', '1871-11', '1871-12']
div = np.zeros(len(date))

tab = pd.DataFrame({'date':date, 'zeros':div})
tab
```

I would like to change directly in the table and not from the list date the value of '1871-1' in '1871-11'.
Maybe you can help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mask

```
tab['date']=tab['date'].mask(tab['date'].eq('1871-1'),'1871-11')

     date  zeros
0  1871-01    0.0
1  1871-02    0.0
2  1871-11    0.0
3  1871-11    0.0
4  1871-12    0.0
```

Alternatively, use np.where

```
tab['date']=np.where(tab['date'].eq('1871-1'),'1871-11',tab['date'])
```

Following your comments below in which you indicate you want this done for multiple values with different prefixes.

Please try:

```
tab['date']=np.where(tab.date.str.contains('-1$'),tab['date']+'1',tab['date'])
```

or

```
tab['date']=tab['date'].mask(tab.date.str.contains('-1$'),tab['date']+'1')
```

Comment: Thanks, and if I have multiple element. Exemple: '1871-1' '1898-1', and so on

Comment: Please try `tab['date']=np.where(tab.date.str.contains('-1$'),tab['date']+'1',tab['date'])`

Comment: Does that help?